# How do I change the scrollbar color in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, customization

Is it possible to change the scrollbar color in emacs? (Note: Not XEmacs)

If it matters, I'm running emacs 22 on Ubuntu 8.10.

Answer (score 3):

In what environment?  In, eg, Carbon EMACS, the scrollbar widgets come from the carbon native set; if so, you can't really change the color.

Comment: Carbon Emacs is now defunct, but what is its contemporary version? Does it have a sequel?

Comment: Several of them. I use eMacs-plus but there are lots. Check the eMacs wiki https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsForMacOS

Answer (score 1):

Shamelessly taken from [the FAQ for XEmacs](http://www.xemacs.neoscientists.org/Documentation/21.5/html/xemacs-faq_5.html)

Here's a recap of how to use resources to change your scrollbar colors:

```
! Motif scrollbars

Emacs*XmScrollBar.Background: skyblue
Emacs*XmScrollBar.troughColor: lightgray

! Athena scrollbars

Emacs*Scrollbar.Foreground: skyblue
Emacs*Scrollbar.Background: lightgray
```

Note the capitalization of Scrollbar for the Athena widget.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I'm running the latest version of Ubuntu (8.10) and the latest version of emacs (22.2.1). Any other suggestions?

Comment: Charlie asks a good question:  What environment are you in?  To answer your question -- yes, I think that only works for XEmacs (sorry for my assumption)

Answer (score 1):

See the Emacs Wiki Site for info about [ScrollBars](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScrollBar)

To Quote from the site:

> GnuEmacs can draw its own “native” scroll bars, which are quite customizable. In my opinion, this also gives the best results for users of ColorTheme. Details follow:
>
> Build GnuEmacs with the following options passed to ./configure:
>
> ```
>          --without-toolkit-scroll-bars --with-x-toolkit=no
> ```
>
> Then try a ColorTheme, or:
>
> ```
> M-x customize-face RET scroll-bar RET
> ```
>
> You can set the foreground/background colors, border color/width, etc. There is a separate variable called scroll-bar-width.

Comment: But what if I am dealing with a pre-built emacs in an installation I can't control?

Comment: try a `M-x describe-variable ret system-configuration-options ret` if it doesn't have the above the settings it doesn't look like you can!